# Simulate user login using MVC Memberships framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I’m developing an application that uses the MVC Membership framework. 
The support people want’s to simulate the users login to understand the problems that the users are reporting. By simulating the user the support staff can see exactly what the users see. I want that the user simulation don’t affect the information related to the user login date or user activity dates.

What is the best approach to implement this requirement using the MVC Membership functions?

Comment: can't you create a user account for support staff? hmm

Comment: That staff already have an account. What we pretend is to give to the staff users the possibility to gain the permissions and the state of a specific user. The user state and permissions will affect the application behavior.

Comment: Can't you just copy the information of the user and give him a new name? So you have all his information, nothing of the original user has changed and you can simply delete him when you are done.

Comment: I just can’t start creating and deleting temporary users just to simulate real ones. It will deteriorate the performance of the application. Furthermore, we just can’t delete users because we store the user activities in log tables.